# Adapter call void

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am beginner in Android so, sorry for my probably noobie question. I've got `RecyclerView` list in my application. I created DataAdapter and Activity for that. I also created two layouts: **favorite_items**(assigned to Data Adapter) and **favorite_activity**(assigned to Activity). In favorite_items layout(Data Adapter) I've got button "Share" and in Activity I've got function(ButtonLogic). I would like to call function from activity but i don't know how. I must add that `RecyclerView` works fine.

**ACTIVITY**

```
public void ButtonsLogic(){

   mShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          String s = Textview.getText().toString();
          Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
          sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
          sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, s);
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share data:"));

      }
});
```

**ADAPTER**

```
public class FavoriteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoriteAdapter.FavoriteViewHolder> {


    //this context we will use to inflate the layout
    private Context mCtx;

    //we are storing all the products in a list
    private List<Favorite> favoriteList;

    //getting the context and product list with constructor
    public FavoriteAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Favorite> favoriteList {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.favoriteList= favoriteList;
    }

    @Override
    public FavoriteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflating and returning our view holder
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorite_items, null);
        return new FavoriteViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FavoriteViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //getting the product of the specified position
        Favorite favorite= quoteModelList.get(position);

        //binding the data with the viewholder views
        holder.Favoritetext.setText(favorite.getFavoriteText());


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return favoriteList.size();
    }


    class FavoriteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView Favoritetext;


        public FavoriteViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Favoritetext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favoritetextview);


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interface like this

```
interface Listener {
    private void onItemClicked(String text);
}
```

and implement it in your Activity. When you construct your adapter, pass this interface

```
public FavoriteAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Favorite> favoriteList, Listener listener) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.favoriteList= favoriteList;
    this.listener = listener
```

}

Set the listener in your bind method

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FavoriteViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //getting the product of the specified position
    Favorite favorite= quoteModelList.get(position);

    //binding the data with the viewholder views


    holder.Favoritetext.setText(favorite.getFavoriteText());
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listener.onIemClicked(/* get text to pass to activity */);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've got one question. In this interface void(onItemClicked) i must add ButtonsLogic()?

Comment: Based on your snippet, you need the text to share. So all you need to do is get the text (in your snippet you get it from the TextView, though getting it from the adapter array/list would be preferred), and then call the interface with that text.
Edit: I misread. Yes, in the interface you would have the buttons logic to fire off the share intent.

Comment: Thank you very much